# How to display value on two different text box

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate total days between start_date and end_date.  Here i have two text box which is one textbox for end_date and other one for total days between start_date and end_date.What i want to do is when user click the button , the end_date textbox filled with end date and total days text box filled with total days . Can anyone help me with it ?

Here's the code.

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtDate').datepicker();
    $('#follow_Date').getDate();
    $('#dura').getValue();
    $('#mark').getValue();


});

function getdate() {
    var sd = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;
    var d = document.getElementById('dura').value;
    var m = document.getElementById('mark').value;

    var date = new Date(sd);
    var newdate = new Date(date);
    var duration = parseInt(d);
    var marking = parseInt(m);


    if ( marking === 1 )
    {
        newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate());
    }
    else if ( marking === 2 )
    {
         newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + duration);
    }
    else if ( marking === 3 )
    {
         newdate.setDate((newdate.getDate() + duration)+1);
    }


    var dd = newdate.getDate();
    var mm = newdate.getMonth()+1;
    var y = newdate.getFullYear();

    var someFormattedDate = y + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById('follow_date').value = someFormattedDate;

}
function getdays()
{
    var days = (follow_date.setdate(follow_date.getDate()) - newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate()));
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date:
    <input id="txtDate" type="text" />
</p>
<p>Duration :
    <input id="dura" type="text" />
</p>

<p>Marks:
    <input id ="mark" type = "text"/>
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" onclick="getdate()" value="Fill Follow Date" />
</p>
<p>End Date:
    <input id="follow_date" type="text" onkeydown="getdate()" />
</p>
<p>Days :
    <input id="days" type="text" onkeydown="getdays()" />
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems like you already know how to set the value of a text input `document.getElementById('follow_date').value = someFormattedDate;`. So what are you asking exactly?

Comment: theres two calculation . for finding end date and total days between start date and end date. the problem is now,when i click the button, only textbox for end date will display the result . the days text box not display anything. do you get me ? :D

Comment: Why don't you set it to seomething then? This should work: `document.getElementById('days').value = getdays();`?! Calling the fucntion with `onkeydown="getdays()"` does "nothing" since you only calculate the date and return it but don't use it there, if you mean that.

Comment: i'd done like what you've said. it only display the value for textbox end date while in textbox days doesnt display anything. do i have to make it like this on button code ? `<input type="button" onclick="getdate();getdays()" value="Fill Follow Date" />`

Comment: No that would just call both functions on click, you should add the functionality to your `getdate()` function to set all values you want when you click the button. It seems like you need to learn general JavaScript basics first, then you understand what happends instead of just guessing. I can write an example as an answer, but it's better when you know how to do it yourself! :)

Comment: noted. Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do in the end, but there are many errors in your code.

Your `getdays` function cannot access the variables from your `getdate` function, e.g. `follow_date` and `newdate`, you need to define global variables or pass them to your function as arguments in order to use them.

Also you're mixing jQuery functions with plain JavaScript (if you even have included jQuery)..

This is a small idea what you need to do to display another variable as your input value, see the comment and added two lines:

```
function getdate() {
    var sd = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;
    var d = document.getElementById('dura').value;
    var m = document.getElementById('mark').value;

    var date = new Date(sd);
    var newdate = new Date(date);
    var duration = parseInt(d);
    var marking = parseInt(m);


    if ( marking === 1 )
    {
        newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate());
    }
    else if ( marking === 2 )
    {
         newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + duration);
    }
    else if ( marking === 3 )
    {
         newdate.setDate((newdate.getDate() + duration)+1);
    }


    var dd = newdate.getDate();
    var mm = newdate.getMonth()+1;
    var y = newdate.getFullYear();

    var someFormattedDate = y + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById('follow_date').value = someFormattedDate;

    // added this two lines, that will set the days to your days input element
    var days = (follow_date.setdate(follow_date.getDate()) - newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate()));
    document.getElementById('days').value = days;
}
```

But as mentioned there are likely more problems with the code, I suggest reading a good JavaScript guide and start with simple things first if you want to unterstand it better, it makes no sense to rewrite your code so it just works I guess.